# TabLayout with Viewpager : Swipe is not smooth

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, webview

I have a Tablayout with Viewpager and 4 fragments. Each fragment has a webview. My issue is every time I swipe between the fragments the swipe is not always accurate. If the horizontal swipe is not accurate I get a scroll bar on the webview thus preventing the swipe to next fragment. I think this is the issue with horizontal & Vertical swipes. I have looked into examples but Its very complicated for me to  implement. Please look into the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.tring.trong.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the adapter class

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    int tabCount;


    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.tabCount = numberOfTabs;

    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
//
                Tab1Fragment tab1 = new Tab1Fragment();
                return tab1;

            case 1:
                Tab2Fragment tab2 = new Tab2Fragment();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3Fragment tab3 = new Tab3Fragment();
                return tab3;

            case 3:
                Tab4Fragment tab4 = new Tab4Fragment();
                return tab4;

            default:
                return null;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

This is the Fragment Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/website_detail_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            >

        </WebView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you need horizontal  Scroll in your webview ?

Comment: No only vertical scrolling.

Comment: try this to disable horizontal scrolling for your webview, `mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);` Hope now you will get smooth scroll of Viewpager

Comment: No sir It didnt work. It works fine for the first three tabs as they are in view. The issue stats with tabs that are only partially in view.

Comment: its because fragments are always recreated.

Comment: Is there anyway to handle this ?